# MongoClient(host=['localhost:PORT'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can this message be removed from every Mongo call (collection.update) using Pymongo?

```
MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)
```

If useful:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.16

mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the output of a command similar to

```
print db
```

Pymongo will not output this message by default; so something else must be.